# Overriding value in heap java programming

Tags: java

I've added to my project a new data structure `Heap<Integer,Integer>` but the only problem I've got is that it prints me only one time the result.

If I have the input:

```
v=10;new(v,20);new(a,22);print(v)
```

at the end of execution

```
Heap={1->20, 2->22},
SymTable={v->1, a->2}
```

But what it gives me:

```
Heap: 1->22
SymTable: a -> 1
       v -> 1
```

It overrides the first value.Here is the code from the controller where is the main part:

```
        HeapAllocation crtStmt1=(HeapAllocation) crtStmt;
        String varI = crtStmt1.getVarname();
        Exp e = crtStmt1.getExpression();
        int i=0;
        Id<Object,Integer> tbl = state.getDict();
        IHeap<Integer,Integer> heap1 = state.getHeap();
        int value= e.eval(tbl, heap1);
        heap1.put(++i, value);

        if (tbl.containsKey(varI))
            tbl.update(varI,i);
        tbl.update(varI, i);
```

The problem I guess is after this line:

```
   heap1.put(++i, value);
```

because for a new operation it doesn't append to the previous one, just overrides it.

Edit:
The implementation of the heap:

```
 public class Heap<Integer,In> implements IHeap<Integer, Integer>,Serializable{
  private Map<Integer, Integer> mapp;
  public Heap(){
      mapp = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

  }
  public void put(Integer index, Integer value){
      mapp.put(index, value);
  }

  public void remove(Integer index){
      try{
          if(isEmpty())
              throw new ExceptionRepo();
          else
              mapp.remove(index);
      }catch (ExceptionRepo ex){
          System.err.println("Error: Heap is empty.");
      }
  }
  public boolean isEmpty(){
      return mapp.isEmpty();
  }
  public Integer get(Integer index){
      return mapp.get(index);
  }
  public boolean containsIndex(Integer index){
      return mapp.containsKey(index);
  }
  public void update(Integer index, Integer value){
      mapp.put(index, value);
  }
  public String toString(){
      Set<Integer> all = mapp.keySet();
      Object[] keysA= all.toArray();
      String res="";
      for(int i=0; i<mapp.size(); i++){
          Integer v = mapp.get(keysA[i]);
          res += keysA[i].toString() + "->" + v.toString() + "\r\n";
      }
      return res;
  }
 }
```

Edit2: Maybe the problem is in the eval function implementation.To be clear, I have a Exp class:

```
 public class Exp{
 public int eval(Id<Object,Integer> tbl)throws ExceptionRepo{
    return 0;
  }
 public String toString(){
    return "";

 }
 public int eval(Id<Object,Integer> tbl,IHeap<Integer,Integer> heap) throws ExceptionRepo{
  return 0;
 }
```

And some derived classes that extends the Exp class.I added a new method in the ConstExp class:

```
 public class ConstExp extends Exp implements Serializable{
int number;
public int eval(Id<Object,Integer> tbl) throws ExceptionRepo{
    return number;
}
public ConstExp(int n){
    number = n;
}
public String toString(){
    return "" + number;
}
public int eval(Id<Object,Integer> tbl,IHeap<Integer,Integer> heap) throws ExceptionRepo{              
    return number;  //THIS IS THE NEW METHOD
}
```

This class should return a value..so for "v=20", after execution of the statement it puts the value 20 in the v based on this class implementation.

```
 If it's useful this is the statement evaluation rule for the heap(that I implemented in the controller up there):

Stack1={new(var,exp)| Stmt2|...}
SymTable1
Heap1
==>
Stack2={Stmt2|...}
let be v=eval(exp,SymTable1,Heap1) in
Heap2 = Heap1 U {newfreelocation ->v}
if var exists in SymTable1 then SymTable2 = update(SymTable1,
var,newfreelocation)
else SymTable2 = add(SymTable1,var, newfreelocation)
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: What is the implementation of this heap? Looks like it behaves like a HashMap instea of a priority queue.

Comment: So it is a HashMap. What is a state? Your code only puts a single value to the heap, thus I expect a single value to be in it.

Comment: Well, the state is the program that I want to be executed.The example from the beginning of the post in a program state.

Comment: I started to feel it. So your language's `new` function stores a key-value pair in a hashmap. What does happen when a simbol (namely `a`) is not defined? This is still too little information. There must be an implementation bug somewhere in your eval function.

Comment: What is a `Heap<Integer, Integer>`? What exactly is the meaning of `v=10;new(v,20);new(a,22);print(v) `? It isn't Java code: what is it?

Comment: @hege_hegedus when the symbol a is not defined it gives me in the heap: 1->20 and in the Table: v : 1. Is ok.Maybe it should be an error in the eval function..

Comment: @EJP To have an idea, my project is called Toy Language.I enter in the main part of my project different statements that are executed based by my implementation.I have defined statements and expressions and after the execution of these statement in my 3 data structures that I implemented:stack,dictionary<Object,Integer>,List it should be the correct values. Now, I have to add a new data structure named Heap and to append it in my project.But here it comes that error.